# Cannot read property 'listPipelines' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I have a function like this

```
vulog.info(''+ ecoder.client);
  ecoder.client.listPipelines({}, function(err, data){
  vulog.info('Inside vuaws.listPipelines');
  if (err) {
    vulog.error('Error in getting pipelines');
    vulog.error(err);
    return;
  }
  vulog.debug(data);
  interviewpipeid[0] = data.Pipelines[0].Id;
  interviewpipeid[1] = data.Pipelines[1].Id;
  vulog.info('Interview Pipeline ID is: ' + interviewpipeid);

 });
```

But when I run this example I am getting this error.

> Cannot read property 'listPipelines' of undefined

How can I debug this particular problem please someone explains to me what is happening here.

The ecoder is from AWS

```
var ecoder = new AWS.ElasticTranscoder(vuconst.encoderconfig);
```

I dont have much idea about nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS ElasticTranscoder Class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder.html) doesn't seem to have a `client` property. It does however have a [`listPipelines` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder.html#listPipelines-property) directly in the `ElasticTranscoder` class. You can try calling `ecoder.listPipelines` directly, without the `.client`.